# Miniature wise what is the size comparison between a centurion and a crisis battlesuit?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Size wise how different is the height of the tau crisis battle suit and the imperium centurions?

Answer (score 1):

They are fairly similar in height, however several factors make it hard to give a single canonical answer.

First off there are several versions of Crisis Suit (CS from here on)... If we ignore "specialty" CS such as Commander/Coldstar/etc there are still two different versions. Add to that the fact that CS come w/ a flying stand and are fairly dynamically poseable which can change the height fairly drastically.

Comment: Is there any in-universe technical data available on the two? Perhaps there's a 'fluff' book that calls out the physical height of a centurion and/or a crisis suit, which would give an objective source instead of trying to physically compare models where scale is already not overly consistent.

Comment: @DavidCEllis for fluff data you might be better off asking on the SciFi&Fantasy stack